# Optimizing Chai Test

Tags: javascript, chai

```
describe('Maestro', function() {
  // Write full test coverage for the Maestro card
  var should = chai.should();

  //Maestro always has a prefix of 5018, 5020, 5038, or 6304, and a length of 12-19.
  var prefix = ['5018', '5020', '5038', '6304'];
  var allLengths = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

  for (var i = 0; i < prefix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < allLengths; j++) {
      it('has a prefix of ' + prefix[i] + ' and a length of ' + (allLengths[j]).toString(), function () {
        detectNetwork('5018XXXXXXXX'.should.equal('Maestro'));
      });
    }
  }
```

I'm writing a Chai test to check the input of a card number of fixed lengths of 12-19 and with each prefix. I am trying to optimize this test so that after the prefix requirement has been satisfied that the rest of the numbers don't matter as long as the card length is met. `detectNetwork` is the function which runs my card number and matches it to a certain card. I'm not sure if it's possible here to write in a code where `detectNetwork('5018XXXXXXXX'.should.equal('Maestro'));` the all the X values in here can be any number and ideally I would want that to change based on the current length value it's based on in the loop. I know I can manually write out each scenario here by doing a for loop only for the prefix and then hard coding the card numbers for each length but that definitely isn't optimal nor practical to do outside of this assignment

Comment: Tests should be optimized for readability as the only validation most tests have is manual code review. I would think that the most readable way to perform the test would be to supply a list of card numbers that demonstrate that the code works as intended, or a list of prefixes and suffixes, if it's necessary for the test to check every prefix for every length.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I see. It just doesn't make sense to me as if my only requirement is having those 4 prefix values of a card a card length of `12-19` digits that it is a hell of a lot of possible combinations to theoretically test. Granted, for this assignment I only need one test case per scenario so my list of test cases is small - I wanted to full proof it for all possible combinations of card numbers

Comment: Theoretically it makes sense to write tests that treat the underlying code as a black box, but some assumptions always need to be made. Personally, I would write 3 cases for every prefix, One for the minimum length, one for the maximum length, and an intermediate length. My assumption is that the code is checking string length for between 12 and 19 characters, not handling each length separately.

Comment: Seems the best way to optimize it. Thanks @CharlesBamford

Comment: Consider a function called concat(str1, str2). A valid test would pass two strings in and expect them to be concatenated. The test shouldn't need to pass every possible pair of strings, or even a statistically significant list of strings to prove that  concat works.